# gltf file renders incorrectly in aframe

Tags: aframe, gltf

Can anyone help me debug a glTF file? It looks ok in Don McCurdy's glTF viewer at https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ (though it's pretty different from how it looks in Blender) but most of its pieces are missing when I use aframe to look at it: https://sgouros.com/scorpii/index1.html. The model is at https://sgouros.com/scorpii/data/scorpii3.glb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the transparent nodes of the model [in most cases should have](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/18235) disabled writing to the depth buffer by their material.

Citing the [Khronos wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Translucency_and_the_depth_buffer)(or citing Don McCurdy citing the wiki):

> The standard method for dealing with translucent objects ... involves disabling writes to the depth buffer and sorting transparent objects and/or polygons based on distance to the camera.

So you could just traverse the mesh and disable depthWrite for transparent objects:

```
model.traverse(node => {
    if (node.isMesh) {
           node.material.depthWrite = !node.material.transparent;
    }
});
```

like i did with the provided model in [this glitch](https://stack-59852899.glitch.me/).

Comment: That makes perfect sense, and you are kind to show me the answer. Thank you very much! I am new enough here that it won't let me vote this answer up, but I tried.